# sinatra, omniauth, launchpad.net strategy unable to get request token

Tags: ruby, oauth, sinatra, omniauth

I'm attempting to pull a request token via https://launchpad.net using sinatra, and a custom omniauth strategy

```
require 'omniauth-oauth'                                                                                                                
require 'oauth/signature/plaintext'                                                                                                     
require 'multi_json'                                                                                                                    
require 'pp'                                                                                                                            

module OmniAuth                                                                                                                         
  module Strategies                                                                                                                     
    class Launchpad < OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth                                                                                       
      option :name, "launchpad"                                                                                                         
      option :client_options, {                                                                                                         
        :authorize_url => 'https://launchpad.net/+authorize-token',                                                                     
        :request_token_url => 'https://launchpad.net/+request-token',                                                                   
        :site => 'https://api.launchpad.net',                                                                                           
        :consumer_key => 'rubystfu',                                                                                                    
        :signature_method => 'PLAINTEXT',                                                                                               
        :signature => '%26'                                                                                                             
      }                                                                                                                                 

      def request_phase                                                                                                                 
        super                                                                                                                           
      end                                                                                                                               

      uid {                                                                                                                             
        raw_info[:name]                                                                                                                 
      }                                                                                                                                 

      info do                                                                                                                           
        {                                                                                                                               
          :description => raw_info['description'],                                                                                      
          :name => raw_info['name'],                                                                                                    
          :display_name => raw_info['display_name'],                                                                                    
          :karma => raw_info['karma'],                                                                                                  
          :self_link => raw_info['self_link'],                                                                                          
          :email => raw_info['email']                                                                                                   
        }                                                                                                                               
      end                                                                                                                               

      extra do                                                                                                                          
        {                                                                                                                               
          :raw_info => raw_info                                                                                                         
        }                                                                                                                               
      end                                                                                                                               

      def raw_info                                                                                                                      
        raw_info                                                                                                                        
      end                                                                                                                               
    end                                                                                                                                 
  end                                                                                                                                   
end
```

I've setup my sinatra app in this fashion

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby                                                                                                                     
require 'rubygems'                                                                                                                      
require 'bundler'                                                                                                                       

Bundler.setup :default, :development, :chonk                                                                                            

require 'sinatra'                                                                                                                       
require 'haml'                                                                                                                          
require 'omniauth-launchpad'                                                                                                            

use Rack::Session::Cookie                                                                                                               

use OmniAuth::Builder do                                                                                                                
  provider :launchpad                                                                                                                   
end                                                                                                                                     

set :sessions, true                                                                                                                     
set :logging, true                                                                                                                      

class ChonkApp < Sinatra::Application                                                                                                   
  helpers do                                                                                                                            
    def check_auth                                                                                                                      
      redirect "/" if not session[:user]                                                                                                
    end                                                                                                                                 
  end                                                                                                                                   

  get '/' do                                                                                                                            
    redirect "/app" if session[:user]                                                                                                   
    haml :index                                                                                                                         
  end                                                                                                                                   

  get '/app' do                                                                                                                         
    check_auth                                                                                                                          
    "#{session[:user]} | <a href='/logout'>logout</a>"                                                                                  
  end                                                                                                                                   

  get '/logout' do                                                                                                                      
    session.clear                                                                                                                       
    redirect '/'                                                                                                                        
  end                                                                                                                                   

  %w(get post).each do |method|                                                                                                         
    send(method, "/auth/:name/callback") do                                                                                             
      auth = request.env['omniauth.auth']                                                                                               
      a = auth.info                                                                                                                     
      session[:user] = "%s %s (%s)" % [a.email, a.name, a.nickname]                                                                     
      redirect "/app"                                                                                                                   
    end                                                                                                                                 
  end                                                                                                                                   

  get '/auth/failure' do                                                                                                                
    "I dunno wtfook happened."                                                                                                          
  end                                                                                                                                   
end
```

The documentation states it needs 3 posted params for this to work:

> To obtain a request token, send a POST request to
>   https://launchpad.net/+request-token. (Note: not api.launchpad.net!)
>   This is the same kind of POST a web browser does when it submits a
>   form. You should submit the following values in form-URL-encoded
>   format.
>
> oauth_consumer_key: Your consumer key oauth_signature_method: The
>   string "PLAINTEXT" oauth_signature: The string "&".
>
> So the HTTP request might look like this:
>
> ```
> POST /+request-token HTTP/1.1
> Host: launchpad.net
> Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> oauth_consumer_key=just+testing&oauth_signature_method=PLAINTEXT&oauth_signature=%26 The response should look something like this:
>
>
> 200 OK
>
> oauth_token=9kDgVhXlcVn52HGgCWxq&oauth_token_secret=jMth55Zn3pbkPGNht450XHNcHVGTJm9Cqf5ww5HlfxfhEEPKFflMqCXHNVWnj2sWgdPjqDJNRDFlt92f
> ```

The only thing I can see that may be incorrect is the signature_method and/or signature. Im pretty new to ruby so any advice is appreciated. The error that is coming back is a '401 unauthorized' and I haven't quite figured out how to print some debugging output on what exactly is being passed to https://launchpad.net during the request.

The link to the documentation for signing requests is here:
https://help.launchpad.net/API/SigningRequests

thanks

p.s. the source for the omniauth-launchpad is https://github.com/battlemidget/omniauth-launchpad, and for the actual application https://github.com/battlemidget/chonk

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with the code. Have you tried putting together the query string yourself and sending it as a cURL request to see if the API accepts it? e.g. `curl --data 'oauth_consumer_key=just+testing&oauth_signature_method=PLAINTEXT&oauth_signature=%26' https://launchpad.net/+request-token`

Comment: Yea when i issue that request it returns both my oauth_token and oauth_token_secret

Comment: As a bit of simple debugging, you could add a line at the beginning of [this method](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-oauth/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth.rb#L28) in the Omniauth gem, something like `warn "callback_url = #{callback_url}" to see what's happening (or use Pry or some other debugging library to help). Remember to remove it once you're done!